# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'conference room' to data dype int

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, relational-database

I have the following SQL below (SQL Server 2008) and I'm trying to figure out why i'm getting this error message. I checked the datatype for the 'type' in question and it is set as char(50). the condition column is only in one table Any ideas?

```
SELECT 
  '' as condition,                                                        
  area,
  type
 FROM d_rooms
 UNION
 SELECT * FROM k_rooms
```

I have also tried the following and it didn't work...same error message

```
cast(type as char(50)) as type
```

Also I have tried this - same error

```
'' AS type --same error
```

Comment: What columns has `k_rooms`? It must have the same (incl. type) as `d_rooms`.

Comment: it has the same columns

Comment: sorry i was wrong before - the columns are not the same - 'condition' is only in one table

Comment: type is reserved word. you should put brackets [type]

Answer (score 1):

The columns must be in the same order when you `UNION` them together, explicitly list them if * isn't working:

```
SELECT 
  condition,                                                        
  area,
  [type]
 FROM d_rooms
 UNION
 SELECT 
  condition = '',                                                        
  area,
  [type] 
FROM k_rooms
```

Updated making assumptions, if condition isn't in both tables then you need to hard-code it in, '' or `NULL`.  The conversion problem definitely looks like it's the result of columns that aren't lined up.

Comment: Goat please look at my edit...columns are not actually the same

Comment: Just take Goat's work and substitute your "'' as condition," for his first "condition,"

Answer (score 0):

If the columns in the two tables really are the same try explicitly stating the columns in the correct order instead of using `SELECT *`:

```
SELECT 
  condition,                                                        
  area,
  type
 FROM d_rooms
 UNION
 SELECT 
  condition,                                                        
  area,
  type
 FROM k_rooms
```

This is a good practice to get into anyways.  Consider the following scenario:

You create a stored proc that contains your original query with `select *`.  This works fine for a year or two and then you add a column to the table k_rooms.  Your stored proc will now break when it is run.

Comment: Abe, please look at my edit. there is actually one column that is different

Comment: My answer still applies.  I don't think your update changes anything.